# Insert Checkbox values in Database using Ajax, & PHP in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to insert the values of all ticked checkboxes in a wordpress database, using ajax. I have a multiple question with multiple option.

Comment: Could you share the code or HTML structure? With your question, I think jQuery with CSS selector can help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for checkbox value input using ajax. Hope you will find your answer.

```
<input id="" name="checkbox_id[]" type="checkbox" value="" > // Checkbox

$('#submitButton').click(function(){
    var checkboxValue = new Array();
    $.each($("input[name='checkbox_id[]']:checked"), function() { //Checkbox by its name
          checkboxValue.push($(this).val());
          // or you can do something to the actual checked checkboxes by working directly with  'this'
          // something like $(this).hide() (only something useful, probably) :P
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submitUrl",
        data: {'checkboxValue':checkboxValue},
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it using plain JavaScript.

```
//add an eventListener to your submit button
document.getElementById( "submitBtn" ).addEventListener( "click", function( event ){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default behavior of the submit button

    //get values of only checked checkboxes and then push them onto an array
    let checkboxArr = array();
    let checkboxNodeList = document.querySelectorAll( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" );
    for ( let i = 0; i < checkboxNodeList.length; i++ ) {
        checkboxArr.push( checkboxNodeList.value );
    }
    //prepare array to be sent
    checkboxArr = encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify( checkboxArr ) );

    //parameters to send in the request
    let parameters = "action=your_php_function_name&checkboxArr=" + checkboxArr;

    //then you would create an XHMLHttpRequest object and send the data
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //set request ( method, wordpress ajax_url, asynchronous )
    xhr.open( "POST", your_wp_localize_script_variable.ajax_url, true );

    //set request header to allow key/value pairs being sent via URL
    xhr.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;" );

    //on success
    xhr.onload = function(){
       //status OK
       if ( this.status == 200 ) {
          console.log( "response->" + JSON.parse( this.responseText );
       }
    }

    //if an error occurs
    xhr.onerror = function(){
        console.log( this.responseText );
    }

    //send the request
    xhr.send( parameters );

});
```

Then on PHP side in the function to which you sent the request to you can retrieve the array of checkbox values like this.

```
//have to decode and strip slashes
$checkboxArr = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST[ 'checkboxArr' ] ) );
```

You can then write data to database as you see fit.

I hope you find this useful.